# How to make Wildfly 10.1 use HTTP/2 Protocol in both HTTPS and HTTP?

Tags: http, https, wildfly, http2

I followed the simple instructions in this [Wildfly 10.1 news](http://wildfly.org/news/) that enables HTTP/2 and TLS protocol on port 8443 and everything went perfectly.

But I would like to enable HTTP/2 protocol also in pages HTTP, getting this protocol in both HTTPS as in the HTTP.

It is possible?

And how I can make this change directly in the standalone-full.xml configuration file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTTP2 works only with SSL/TLS

Browsers do not support HTTP2 without encryption

Comment: OP didn't say they were using a browser. And if using non-standard port 8443 they may have a webserver in front of this that they want to to talk HTTP/2 to wildfly with. Apache mod_proxy_http2 allows this. Though in my view server to server HTTP/2 gains are small and not worth the hassle until HTTP/2 server support becomes for mainstream.

Comment: Hi.

Thx for the message.

So there is no way to run HTTP/2 protocol in a browser without HTTPS?

Answer (score 4):

HTTP/2 is is enabled by default on both the HTTP and HTTPS ports, however most browsers (with the exception of internet explorer) do not support HTTP/2 without encryption.

Comment: Hellou 

Thx for the message.

I also test in IE 11 and de HTTP/2 do not support without encryption.

So there is no way to run HTTP/2 protocol without HTTPS?

Comment: If you want a browser to use it then you have to use HTTPS (I thought Microsoft was going to implement plaintext support as well but it looks like they changed their mind). There are still non-browser clients that cause use plaintext though, e.g. if you use the Wildfly reverse proxy you can use plaintext HTTP/2 to communicate with the backends.